# Updating error message of required validator clientside using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

Is it possible to update the ErrorMessage on a required validator client side using jQuery.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$("#<%=rbl1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
       switch ($('#<%= rbl1.ClientID %> input:radio:checked').val()) {
             case 'Yes':
                    $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').text('Label text');
                    $('<%=vReq1.ClientID%>').Attr('ErrorMessage','Text 1'); 
                   break;
             case 'No':
                     $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').text('Other Label text');
                    $('#<%=vReq1.ClientID %>').Attr('ErrorMessage', 'Text 2'); 
                   break;
             default:
                    $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').text('Other Text');
            };
```

});

The above code updates the label text fine but not the validator errormessage values

Thanks in advance

Zaps

Comment: yes, it is possible to alter the content of any html node using javascript. post the snippet of html source and we can provide the answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah....got it:

```
$('#<%=vReq1.ClientID %>').attr('errormessage', 'Text 2');
```